# C++ CRTP(template pattern) question

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

following piece of code does not compile, the problem is in `T::rank` not be inaccessible (I think) or uninitialized in parent template.

Can you tell me exactly what the problem is?
is passing rank explicitly the only way?    or is there a way to query tensor class directly?

Thank you

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template<class T, // size_t N,
         class enable = void>
struct tensor_operator;

// template<class T, size_t N>
template<class T>
struct tensor_operator<T, typename boost::enable_if_c< T::rank == 4>::type > {
    tensor_operator(T &tensor) : tensor_(tensor) {}
    T& operator()(int i,int j,int k,int l) {
        return tensor_.layout.element_at(i, j, k, l);
    }
    T &tensor_;
};

template<size_t N, typename T = double>
// struct tensor : tensor_operator<tensor<N,T>, N> {
struct tensor : tensor_operator<tensor<N,T> > {
    static const size_t rank = N;
};

 tensor <4> D;  // compiler attempts to instantiate undefined template, not specialization
```

I know the workaround, however am interested in mechanics of template instantiation for self-education

Comment: Could it be related to this bug that I found in visual studio? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/354162/seemingly-valid-dependant-types-in-nested-template-not-accepted

Comment: @kirill g++ 4.3.  I forgot to add last line with instantiation, fixed now

Comment: @evan it does look similar indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CRTP the base class template take advantage of the fact that member function bodies (definitions) are not instantiated until long after their declarations. In your code the base class depends on incomplete type.

Comment: This answer is indeed correct. It causes an SFINAE failure for `T::rank` (because the `::rank` member has not yet been declared) because the point of instantiation is prior to the point of instantiation of `tensor<4>`. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287 for some insight into related issues.

Answer (score 2):

Am I the only one looking at an infinite recursion here ?

- `tensor<N,T>` depends on `tensor_operator< tensor<N,T> >`
- `tensor_operator< tensor<N,T> >` depends on `tensor<N,T>`

I don't recall a situation where I used a `Derived` class property to decide whether or not to instantiate `Base`, but it does seem to me like this would cause infinite recursion to occur.

Here is the error on gcc 3.4.2:

```
 In instantiation of `tensor<4ul, double>':
41:   instantiated from here
33: error: invalid use of undefined type
                          `struct tensor_operator<tensor<4ul, double>, void>'
19: error: declaration of `struct tensor_operator<tensor<4ul, double>, void>'
```

The issue here seems to be that the instantiation of `tensor_operator<N,T>` depends on the instantiation of `tensor_operator<N,T>`...

Comment: I do not think it's recursion problem.  I think maybe because rank is specified after parent template is instantiated, it is simply not there?